# is it correct to ask "Have you come out of some place"

Tags: grammar

I want to know if this sentence is a proper way to use.

> Have you come out of the shop.
>
> Have you come out of the building.

thanks for any help.

Comment: Please provide some context on what you want to ask exactly, what the discussion is about.

Comment: .. for example, can you suggest a situation where you might want to say this? Are you talking on a mobile phone to somebody and you want to know where they are? Have you met somebody in th street and you want to know what they have been doing?

Comment: Context is like, somebody shopping inside a shopping mall and you want to know if they have left the shopping mall. I feel something odd about the sentence in the question. but I am not quite getting what wrong with that.

Comment: @JavaLatte sounds like speaking on the phone ?!

Comment: @Cardinal, in some cultures it is common to ask "where have you come from" and "where are you going" when you meet somebody in the street. It's just a stock question like "how are you?". Or maybe the shop or building is a place where immoral activities take place....

Comment: @JavaLatte You too right, we also have those in our culture (Persian). However, I meant that the OP's sentences are similar to conversations on the phone.

Comment: @Cardinal. yes this question came to my mind while I was asking this question over the phone. So I wanted to verify its correctness.

Answer (score 2):

The word [come](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/come) is mainly used in connection with coming toward the speaker (Are you coming to me) or the listener (I will come to you). Note that the link does contain a meaning **LEAVE**, but to my mind both examples imply not just leaving, but coming toward somebody.

If you are outside a shopping mall and you are talking on the phone to somebody that was previously inside the shopping mall but you are not sure where they are now, you can say

> Have you come out of the shopping mall?

If you are inside the mall and you want to know whether the other person is still in the mall, you cannot use **come**, because the person would be going away from you. You would say:

> Have you gone out of the shopping mall?
>
> Have you left the shopping mall?
>
> Are you still in the shopping mall?

Comment: +1 for *If you are **inside** the mall...* If you'd gone ***into*** the mall with a friend, become separated, and then received a text from him saying *Have you come out of the mall?*, you could be quite certain that your friend must now be ***outside*** the mall. The only context where it would be credible for the friend to use *come out* if he was still inside would be if he was on a continuous voice call "guiding" you through the mall (in which case one might allow that he's temporarily thinking of *himself* as being "there with you", because yours is the important end of the conversation).

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with these sentences.

A: Have you come out of the shop?

B: No, I am still in.  Do you want me to buy anything for you?

A: Have you come out of the building?

B: Yes, I have.  By the way, do you want me to get anything from the building?

"Come out of" is also a phrasal verb; it means to result from, to be the result of something. For example:

I hope something good will come out of this mess.